# Facebook app in canvas page vs redirect to website

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-authentication

I'm developing a Facebook app and wondering what advantages there are to using facebook's canvas page over just doing a JavaScript redirect to my website once a user accepts or returns to my Facebook app.  Seems like I can do most things from my website, so why even have a canvas page?  What can't I do from my website?

Is the user required to authorize my website through Facebook connect even after they've authorized my Facebook app?  If so, I guess that's 1 advantage to a canvas page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One example you can't use facebook credits on your website. Facebook users trust app canvas apps more than external sites long-term. External sites are also less integrative with new game features like scores and achievements.

The user is not required to re-authorize on canvas if he is already authorized on your site (which is the same domain and appid).

hope this helps

Comment: Facebook credits is an interesting feature to have, are they used much?  Is Facebook pushing this?

Comment: They are not pushing it, but all other virtual currency providers are forbidden by policy.

Comment: yes, it's pretty popular, 2nd way of making money on the platform besides ads.